# How to make spring boot never issue session cookie?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm developing Restful API server by using spring boot. I configured my project to use basic authentication as below.

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEVER).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole("USER").and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
    ...
}
```

But when I tested the API by Chrome-Postman-Plugin, after first call, server never require user credential. And I noticed that 'JSESSIONID' cookie was created.

There are no other security configurations in my project. I wonder why this happens...

Comment: Does your configuration class extends the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Comment: Yes. I edited my code snippet. I want to sure my api server does not manage any session..

Comment: OK, first,let's verify that the authentication is enforced. Can you try replacing your configuration with this:http.csrf()
    .disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Have you tried using `SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`. There is a subtle difference between `STATELESS` and `NEVER` in the [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html):

`STATELESS`: Spring Security will never create an `HttpSession` and it will never use it to obtain the `SecurityContext`.

`NEVER`: Spring Security will never create an `HttpSession`, **but will use the HttpSession if it already exists**.

So I would suggest that you clear all your cookies, switch it to `STATELESS` and try again. It could be that you had already an `HttpSession` when you switched to `NEVER`.

Comment: Kudos for warning about the ambiguity.

Comment: what if I want to use the session, but don't want spring security to create one?

Comment: I used STATELESS, but getting the error
localhost redirected you too many times. I tried after clearing the cookies too.

I used all these. But everything else is fine except for the sessionManagement thing.

csrf().disable()
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
.formLogin().disable()
.httpBasic().disable()
.logout().disable()

Answer (score 6):

its work for me 
"So I would suggest that you clear all your cookies, switch it to STATELESS and try again. It could be that you had already an HttpSession when you switched to NEVER."

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and().httpBasic();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used the following options

```
.csrf().disable()
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
.formLogin().disable()
.httpBasic().disable()
.logout().disable()
```

Getting the error
**localhost redirected you too many time**

I tried after clearing the cookies.
But the moment I remove the following option/line
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()...
It works good. This is for oauth2login(). May be oauth2login() requires this session state. What could be the explanation?

And when I do not have this
.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()...
Then, it uses the cookie. I use google auth, so, once I logged in, it allows subsequent calls without the need to authenticate.
All of this behavior sound reasonable and as expected.

For security reasons, I was told by an expert, to turn off cookies. I do not know what this means other than turning off the session...

Answer (score 0):

Spring 6 deprecates `http.sessionManagement()` and schedules it for removal in Spring 7.

The replacement is straightforward:

```
http.sessionManagement(smc -> smc.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));
```

`smc` is an instance of `SessionManagementConfigurer<HttpSecurity>`