# Turn off HttpSession in Spring boot without enabling Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, jsessionid, sessionstate-timeout

I am building a RESTful web API in Spring Boot with my own implementation of JWT Authentication and my own authorization as well (not Spring Security). I simply wish to turn off JSESSIONID and run completely stateless, but the only documentation I can find is about turning off session only after *enabling* Spring Security (see here: [How to make spring boot never issue session cookie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387003/how-to-make-spring-boot-never-issue-session-cookie) for example). I don't want Spring Security and I don't want HttpSession or JSESSIONID either.

Does setting server.session.timeout=0 in application.properties work? The doc does not specify the behavior if the timeout is set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

I opened a [Spring GitHub Issue about this a few months ago](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30292), and the response was that Spring MVC does not create sessions on its own. In my case, I saw that, indeed, the simplest form of a Controller did not create a session, it was something else in my application that was doing so.