# how to add a new product using admin rest api?

Tags: spring-boot, shopify, resttemplate, shopify-app, shopify-template

I am writing on the **Shopify admin API**. I am trying to store a new product through Spring boot REST template. It shows an error. I read an article. that said, "I want to change **read and write access** in the private app". I changed it to read and write mode. But The read mode is working fine. When I try to add a new product. I am getting the error.

**Request:**

Method : **POST**

```
{
    "product": {
        "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
        "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
        "vendor": "Burton",
        "product_type": "Snowboard",
        "published": false
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <noscript>
            <a href="https://app.shopify.com/services/login/identity?destination_uuid=9b4d5083-3355-4828-93dd-f077e9531664&amp;return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.shopify.com%2Fservices%2Flogin%2Fidentity_callback%3Fshop_name%3DFestivya%26state%3DRFvJCqXh64NCu1FGcxpD8vzVFSJrDVuDkTuz9exEjDjFgjbjXD5X8KFDXQu4LKOjOahYF0Bid_Dy2ejkD8yUu4mIHpKUT2aT0fpiAIhROlhT9NxAU3QkzBMeb715ANSGOon1duh3pqkRlZD0URqr3B8YUzcTC1lA8BpN5Thjg--LIpOKpJHbtE6FlbBQ-yHZ8dq3RDJilr9pCo42I3owe-wOj3Z7gvQ-IOZ_h_xNtKY%253D&amp;ui_locales=en&amp;upgradeable=true&amp;ux=shop">Continue</a>
        </noscript>
        <script type="text/javascript">
      window.location = "https:\/\/app.shopify.com\/services\/login\/identity?destination_uuid=9b4d5083-3355-4828-93dd-f077e9531664\u0026return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.shopify.com%2Fservices%2Flogin%2Fidentity_callback%3Fshop_name%3DFestivya%26state%3DRFvJCqXh64NCu1FGcxpD8vzVFSJrDVuDkTuz9exEjDjFgjbjXD5X8KFDXQu4LKOjOahYF0Bid_Dy2ejkD8yUu4mIHpKUT2aT0fpiAIhROlhT9NxAU3QkzBMeb715ANSGOon1duh3pqkRlZD0URqr3B8YUzcTC1lA8BpN5Thjg--LIpOKpJHbtE6FlbBQ-yHZ8dq3RDJilr9pCo42I3owe-wOj3Z7gvQ-IOZ_h_xNtKY%253D\u0026ui_locales=en\u0026upgradeable=true\u0026ux=shop";
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like this issue is from shopify.

Comment: @prince hi i tried that it is not working can you please help me ?  i am in urgent

Comment: please tell me u there?

Comment: i cant help you because i havnt used shopify, but why havnt you posted the actual error you are getting?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal My apologies, I didn't pay attention to your message, but I don't use `shopify`

Answer (score 0):

This is not a API permission issue. In that case you will get a related error message. This issue is because of sending cookies with POST request. As per [Shopify documentation](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/guides/using-postman):

> Shopify prevents HTTP Basic Auth POST requests that have cookies,
>   which can cause POST calls to fail. If your POST call fails, then you
>   should try clearing your cookies.

Just disable the cookies. For that I think yor are looking for [Session Creation Policy](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/http/SessionCreationPolicy.html).

> **STATELESS**: 
>   Spring Security will never create an HttpSession and it will never use it to obtain the SecurityContext

For more information have a look at this [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42587808/2803788).

Answer (score 0):

In your Web Security Configuration file, which is inherited from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`, like:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

in the method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception` define session management to **`STATELESS`** like this:

```
BasicAuthProperties properties = basicAuthProperties();
http.requestMatchers().antMatchers(properties.getPath())
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .csrf().disable();
```